# Logging in Azure Web App with Enterprise Library

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, enterprise-library

Is it possible to use Enterprise Library for logging errors in my Azure Web APP?

Comment: It is, but some custom coding may be required depending on where you want the logs to go.

Comment: Can you point me to a link which shows the implementation. As per my research I see only Web/Worker role  can use EntLib and not Web App

Answer (score 0):

Probably, but where would this data live? In log files? If you are running multiple Azure regions, you'll have log files in multiple places. Also how would you query for data when you need to trouble shoot? Detect patterns, aggregate, and perform calculations, etc?

I think you'll run into a lot of operational issues with traditional log files, especially with a high traffic sites.

Azure provides Application Insights too. I would look into that first before looking into writing to log files.